# HttpWebRequest getResponse not matching WireShark

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, wireshark, getresponse

When making a specific GET request, it seems there is a chunk of html missing from the center of the html response. I can't seem to figure out how its being removed. If you run the sample code and record it with Wireshark. You'll see that Wireshark has more html data than the result in the sample has. (Search for 'french' in both; you'll notice that it is missing from the sample yet it shows up in wireshark).

```
static string ReadHTML(string urlAddress)
        {
            urlAddress = "http://www.ebay.com/sch/Dress-Shirts-/57991/i.html?_fln=1&_dmd=1&_ipg=200&_from=R40&_dcat=57991&LH_ItemCondition=3000&_nkw=&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1";
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlAddress) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1";
            request.Host = "www.ebay.com";
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,*");
            //request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.CookieContainer.Add(new System.Net.Cookie("JSESSIONID", "989EDC0DF3234BF32A2544E4FA96C314") { Domain = request.Host });//JSESSIONID=989EDC0DF3234BF32A2544E4FA96C314
            request.CookieContainer.Add(new System.Net.Cookie("npii", "btguid/4948662a1540a1c448711d0effdd49bb58fe33af^cguid/4948bab11540a56603d04eb0fd0d7c0c58fe33af^") { Domain = request.Host });//npii=btguid/4948662a1540a1c448711d0effdd49bb58fe33af^cguid/4948bab11540a56603d04eb0fd0d7c0c58fe33af^
            request.CookieContainer.Add(new System.Net.Cookie("ebay", "%5Esbf%3D%2320000000000000000000210%5E") { Domain = request.Host });//ebay=%5Esbf%3D%2320000000000000000000210%5E
            request.CookieContainer.Add(new System.Net.Cookie("ns1", "=BAQAAAVQr0QFlAAaAANgASVkAJ2pjNjl8NjAxXjE0NjE1MTgzNjIxNjleXjFeM3wyfDV8NHw3XjFeMl40XjNeMTJeMTJeMl4xXjFeMF4xXjBeMV42NDQyNDU5MDc17HliWNBjA7nLq7R3ubPYrU6hFOk*") { Domain = request.Host });
            request.CookieContainer.Add(new System.Net.Cookie("dp1", "bu1p/QEBfX0BAX19AQA**5900276a^bl/US5ae15aea^") { Domain = request.Host });
            request.CookieContainer.Add(new System.Net.Cookie("nonsession", "CgADLAAFXHvryMwDKACBghPVqNDk0ODY2MmExNTQwYTFjNDQ4NzExZDBlZmZkZDQ5YmI2iA27") { Domain = request.Host });
            request.CookieContainer.Add(new System.Net.Cookie("s", "CgAD4ACBXIEVqNTBkYjAwODExNTQwYTU2MTc4NDcxNWIyZmZjMzkyNWIA7gCVVyBFajMGaHR0cDovL3d3dy5lYmF5LmNvbS9zY2gvRHJlc3MtU2hpcnRzLS81Nzk5MS9pLmh0bWw/X2Zsbj0xJl9kbWQ9MSZfaXBnPTIwMCZfZnJvbT1SNDAmX2RjYXQ9NTc5OTEmTEhfSXRlbUNvbmRpdGlvbj0zMDAwJl9ua3c9JkxIX0NvbXBsZXRlPTEmTEhfU29sZD0xGTda/A**") { Domain = request.Host });
            if (request == null)
                return "";

            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            if (response == null)
                return "";

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                return "";

            Stream s2 = response.GetResponseStream();
            if (response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
                s2 = new GZipStream(s2, CompressionMode.Decompress);
            else if (response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
                s2 = new DeflateStream(s2, CompressionMode.Decompress);

            StreamReader sr = null;

            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
            {
                sr = new StreamReader(s2);
            }
            else
            {
                sr = new StreamReader(s2, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            }

            string data = sr.ReadToEnd();

            response.Close();
            return data;
        }
```

You can also simulate the GET request through PostMan (plugin for chrome) and see the exact same html response that Wireshark is getting from the request which is different from the result in the sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the 'Text Visualizer' in Visual Studio was showing an incomplete response. The data was always there. Just the debugger was wrong.

Now I know not to trust it.